# How to get rid of issue 'Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot' when working with XYPlot

Tags: java, android, xml, androidplot

I'm trying to familiarize myself with android XYPlot, using android studio 3.5. 
I have tested several examples first, and I'm ending up with the same error - 
`Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot`
and then app crashes.

I would really appreciate any suggestion to get rid of this issue. Thank you!

**What I did:**
Below shows logcat output of such one of the examples ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206482/androidplot-xyplot-doesnt-show-up-on-graphical-layout-in-xml)) I tried. I updated the Gradle with XYPlot library and also as I noticed when searching I wanted to update ProGuard too. Updated ProGuard is also mentioned at the end.

**main_activity.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
        androidplot.gridPadding="4dp|4dp|4dp|4dp"
        androidplot.ticksPerDomainLabel="2"
        androidplot.ticksPerRangeLabel="4"
        andsroidplot.title="A Simple XYPlot Example"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="527dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Main Activity**

```
package com.example.plot_testmy2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.androidplot.xy.LineAndPointFormatter;
import com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYSeries;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot;
import com.androidplot.xy.XYSeries;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private XYPlot plot;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // initialize our XYPlot reference:
        plot = (XYPlot) findViewById(R.id.mySimpleXYPlot);

        // add a new series
        XYSeries mySeries = new SimpleXYSeries(
                Arrays.asList(0, 25, 55, 2, 80, 30, 99, 0, 44, 6),
                SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY, "series1");
        plot.addSeries(mySeries, new LineAndPointFormatter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.xml.f1));

        /*commented

        // reposition the domain label to look a little cleaner:
        plot.position(plot.getDomainLabelWidget(), // the widget to position
                45,                                // x position value, in this case 45 pixels
                XLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_LEFT,   // how the x position value is applied, in this case from the left
                0,                                 // y position value
                YLayoutStyle.ABSOLUTE_FROM_BOTTOM, // how the y position is applied, in this case from the bottom
                AnchorPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM);       // point to use as the origin of the widget being positioned

         */

        plot.centerOnRangeOrigin(60);
        plot.centerOnDomainOrigin(5);
    }
}
```

**Logcat output :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.plot_testmy2, PID: 29804
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.plot_testmy2/com.example.plot_testmy2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.plot_testmy2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.halfhp.fig.FigException: Error while parsing key: ticksPerDomainLabel value: 2
        at com.androidplot.Plot.loadAttrs(Plot.java:563)
        at com.androidplot.Plot.init(Plot.java:403)
        at com.androidplot.Plot.<init>(Plot.java:324)
        at com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.<init>(XYPlot.java:143)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.plot_testmy2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
     Caused by: com.halfhp.fig.FigException: Error while parsing key: ticksPerDomainLabel value: 2
        at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.configure(Fig.java:300)
        at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.configure(Fig.java:208)
        at com.androidplot.Plot.loadAttrs(Plot.java:561)
        at com.androidplot.Plot.init(Plot.java:403) 
        at com.androidplot.Plot.<init>(Plot.java:324) 
        at com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.<init>(XYPlot.java:143) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.plot_testmy2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such public method (case insensitive): setticksPerDomainLabel in class com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.getMethodByName(Fig.java:110)
        at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.getSetter(Fig.java:116)
        at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.configure(Fig.java:274)
        at com.halfhp.fig.Fig.configure(Fig.java:208) 
        at com.androidplot.Plot.loadAttrs(Plot.java:561) 
        at com.androidplot.Plot.init(Plot.java:403) 
        at com.androidplot.Plot.<init>(Plot.java:324) 
        at com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot.<init>(XYPlot.java:143) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.plot_testmy2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

**gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.plot_testmy2"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation "com.androidplot:androidplot-core:1.5.7"
}
```

**ProGuard :**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keep class com.androidplot.**{*;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.halfhp.fig.FigException: Error while parsing key: ticksPerDomainLabel value: 2**

```
 <com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
        androidplot.gridPadding="4dp|4dp|4dp|4dp"
        androidplot.ticksPerDomainLabel="2" <--- this line is causing the problem
        androidplot.ticksPerRangeLabel="4"
        andsroidplot.title="A Simple XYPlot Example"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="527dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" />
```

remove these:

```
    androidplot.gridPadding="4dp|4dp|4dp|4dp"
    androidplot.ticksPerDomainLabel="2" <--- this line is causing the problem
    androidplot.ticksPerRangeLabel="4"
    andsroidplot.title="A Simple XYPlot Example"
```

And it should work.

I've never seen dotted properties on XML attributes, it should either be underscore(_) or nothing at all

These are all the possible [Attributes](https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/androidplot-core/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml) this view accepts.

None of the ones listed above are written there, they just don't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works... :) I just removed the mentioned 4 lines in my xml and then executed the app. Thanks a lot again for sharing the useful resource too.

Answer (score 0):

the class references R.layout.activity_main while the XML is named main_activity.xml is this correct?

plus there are no andsroidplot.*** attributes, please use ap: instead 
example

`ap:title="A Simple XY Plot"`

and don't forget to add

`xmlns:ap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

to the root tag of your layout (android studio will do it for you with yellow/red pop-up)

and finally please refer to this page for more info regarding the dependency

https://github.com/halfhp/androidplot/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I just tried by removing the above mentioned (accepted answer) 4 lines from my xml and then it works.